# Uninstall joomla from xampp

Tags: joomla

I've installed xampp on local computer (local host) and then installed joomla on xampp, now I need to remove only the joomla completely from xampp. How do I do it.

Answer (score 1):

Try locating in ../xampp/htdocs/you-folder. You can delete the whole folder for your website files.

As for database, run XAMPP and type localhost in your browser. Navigate to your database and delete it.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Delete site folder via Explorer, delete database via phpMyAdmin.